# How to interrupt a modal segue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I created modal segues with xcode's interface builder using storyboards. So I don't have any code about these segues.I wanna stop one of these modal segues if "BOOL permission = NO". If "BOOL permission = YES" modal segue will work normally. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't interrupt a segue but what you can do is choose whether to call it or not.

Instead of having the segue start from a button (for example) you should have it start from the view controller. Then give the segue an identifier "myModalSegue".

Then connect a method to the button...

```
- (IBAction)segueButtonPressed
{
    if (user.hasPermission) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"meModalSegue" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Now that button will only perform trigger the segue if the user has permission.

Comment: Ok but i am new on stack, so i dont know how to accept

Comment: @user3753628 hit the tick next to the answer. :)

Comment: @user3753628 no worries :D Welcome to Stack Overflow anyway :D if you get into it it becomes addictive. I've learnt a hell of a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you can give your segues an identifier by clicking on the segue line, going to the attributes inspector and entering an identifier, for example `mySegue`.

In your code you can then check if the user has permission by connecting your button to an `IBAction`, and checking the permission bool.

```
-(IBAction)mySegueButtonPressed {
    if (permission) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:nil];
    }
}
```